# How to draw many textured quads faster, and retain glScissor (or something like it)?

Tags: c++, performance, opengl

I'm using OpenGL 4 and C++11.

Currently I make a whole bunch of individual calls to `glDrawElements` using separate VAOs with a separate VBO and an IBO.

I do this because the texture coords change for each, and my Vertex data features the texture coords. I understand that there's some redundent position information in this vertex data; however, it's always -1,-1,1,1 because I use a translation and a scale matrix in my vertex shader to then position and scale the vertex data.

The VAO, VBO, IBO, position and scale matrix and texture ID are stored in an object. It's one object per quad.

Currently, some of the drawing would occur like this:

1. Draw a quad object via (`glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT,0)`). The bound VBO is just -1,-1,1,1 and the IBO draws me a quad. The bound VBO contains the texture coords of a common texture (same texture used to texture all drawn quads). Matrix transformations on shader position it.
2. Repeat with another quad object
3. `glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST)` is called and the position information of the preview quad is used in a call to `glScissor`
4. Next quad object is drawn; only the parts of it visible from the previous quad are actually shown.
5. Draw another quad object

The performance I'm getting now is  acceptable but I want it faster because I've only scratched the surface of what I have in mind. So I'm looking at optimizing. So far I've read that I should:

1. Remove the position information from my vertex data and just  keep texture coords. Instead bind a single position VBO at the start of drawing quads so it's used by all of them.

   But I'm unsure how this would work? Because I can only have one VBO active at any one time.

   Would I then have to call `glBufferSubData` and update the texture coordinates prior to drawing each quad? Would this be better performance or worse (a call to `glBindVertexArray` for every object or a call to `glBufferSubData`?)

   Would I still pass the position and scale as matrices to the shader, I would I take that opportunity to also update the position info of the vertices as well as the texture coords? Which would be faster?
2. Create one big VBO with or without an IBO and update the vertex data for the position (rather than use a transformation and scale matrix) of each quad within this. It seems like this would be difficult to manage.

   Even if I did manage to do this; I would only have a single `glDraw` call; which sounds fast. Is this true? What sort of performance impact does a single `glBindVertexArray` call have over multiple?

   I don't think there's any way to use this method to implement something like the `glScissor` call that I'm making now?
3. Another option I've read is instancing. So I draw the quad however many times I need it; which means I would pass the shader an array of translation matrices and an array of texture coords?

   Would this be a lot faster?

   I think I could do something like the `glScissor` test by passing an additional array of booleans which defines whether the current quad should be only drawn within the bounds of the previous one. However, I think this means that for each `gl_InstanceID` I would have to traverse all previous instances looking for true and false values, and it seems like it would be slow.

I'm trying to save time by not implementing all of these individually. Hopefully an expert can point me towards which is probably better. If anyone has an even better idea, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can have multiple VBO attached to different attributes!

following seqence binds 2 vbos to attribs 0 & 1, note that glBindBuffer() binds buffer temporarily and actual VBO assignment to attrib is made during glVertexAttribPointer().

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,buf1);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, ...);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,buf2);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, ...);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

The fastest way to provide quad positions & sizes is to use texture and sample it inside vertex shader. Of course you'd need at least RGBA (x,y,width,height) 16bits / channel texture. But then you can update quad positions using glTexSubImage2D() or you could even render them via FBO.

Everything other than that will perform slower, of course if you want we can elaborate about using uniforms, attribs in vbos or using attribs without enabled arrays for them.

Putting all together:

- use single vbo, store quad id in it (int) + your texturing data
- prepare x,y,w,h texture, define mapping from quad id to this texture texcoord ie: u=quad_id&0xFF , v=(quad_id>>8) (for texture 256x256 max 65536 quads)
- use vertex shader to sample displacement and size from that texture (for given quad_id stored in attribute (or use vertex_ID/4 or vertex_ID/6)
- fill vbo and texture
- draw everything with single drawarrays of draw elements

Comment: First, how the hell did you get that username?

Second, please elaborate.

Actually, I see how using texture info would be fastest. What else can you use a texture for?

Comment: I think it was default user name, never bothered to change it :)

Comment: Note that in case of using vbo you need to provide pos & size for every vertex (4 or even 6 per quad). When using texture you need to store in vbo texel address (quad id) where such info can be fetched from texture.

Comment: Thanks for expanding on your suggestion. With this method, couldn't I draw using Instanced Drawing, so I would only need 6 vertices, or 4 and an IBO and then use the `gl_InstanceID` as my QuadID? Would that make it even faster? Because then there's no need to pass anything; I could use two textures, one with positions, the other with UV coords of my actual visible texture?

Comment: Yes, indeed you don't need to pass anything. But many GL implementors don't like it :( So for better compatibility pass at least 1 attrib :) From my experience it is wise to use this unwanted attrib for locating your primitive on {pos,size} texture so you are not quad order dependent (gl_PrimitiveID).

Comment: Using this technique may not be faster than using pure vbo originals but greatly simplifies & speeds up pos&size updates. Also it makes possible to accelerate these updates using rendering via FBO (for quad animations - similary to 100% gpu particle systems).

Comment: wouldn't one of the needed attributes be my original 4 vertices? And for the other commend (from someone else?) which technique may not be faster?

Comment: Sure you can use this attrib as you wish, good GL implementations won't need it. And yes, you can use it as vertex displacement from quad center which will be moved additionally by position sampled from texture. PS: saying 'may not be faster' i mean that any performance gains can be measurable if total number of rendered pixels (samples) is not too big, otherwise bottle neck would be located in fragment pipeline rather than vertex/geometry.